# Ritalin/Concerta/Methylphenidate is an amphetamine?

Tags: biochemistry, amines, drugs, medicinal-chemistry, pharmacology

FIDE (the governing body of international chess competition) says [here](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/WADA%20Anti%20Doping.pdf):

> The most relevant banned substances for chess are:

> • Amphetamines – e.g. Adderall, [Ritalin](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3433/what-ever-happened-to-the-methylphenidate-synthesiser-and-his-family)

> (...)

Image:

[image]

I think either Ritalin should be in a separate category called [methylphenidate](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61001/what-does-it-mean-for-meth-or-any-other-compound-to-be-pure) or Adderall and Ritalin are categorised under 'stimulants (that you need a prescription for but don't have)' (then you can add vyvanse, desoxyn, concerta, etc) or something because afaik Ritalin/Concerta/Methylphenidate is not an amphetamine.

Or am I wrong: is Ritalin/Concerta/Methylphenidate actually an amphetamine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, I'll mention that I'm not an expert on psychoactive drugs and their classifications; this is just based on my understanding of the situation as a chemist.

As far as chemical structures go, Ritalin (methylphenidate) probably should *not* be considered as an amphetamine:

[image: Structures of methylphenidate and amphetamine]

This comparison (where I've highlighted the amphetamine core in blue) might make it look as if Ritalin is derived from an amphetamine. To a certain extent that is true, but the general class of [*amphetamines*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substituted_amphetamine) doesn't actually allow arbitrary substitution of the amphetamine core. In particular, the name *amphetamine* is derived from *α-methylphenethylamine*, which explicitly specifies the methyl group at the α-position (i.e. next to the $\ce{NH2}$ group). To stick something on the end of that methyl group, as is the case in Ritalin, would invalidate this.*

A more technically correct, and general, term that would encompass both the amphetamines as well as Ritalin would just be something that took away the requirement for the α-methyl group. In other words, we are looking for just [*phenethylamines*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substituted_phenethylamine).

As for the legal technicalities: I am pretty sure that most phenethylamines are controlled drugs because of their psychoactive properties, and hence are likely to be on the list of banned substances. However, since I did not (and probably won't) read the rules in great detail, I'll avoid asserting that "phenethylamines" could be used as a drop-in replacement in there.

---

* The [table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substituted_amphetamine#Structure) does actually show one example where the methyl group is modified to an ethyl group. However, I guess that would still be considered a very small change, compared to the piperidine ring in Ritalin.

Comment: thanks orthocresol♦. God bless you for this. did you add the arrow yourself? or did you get the image (including the arrow) somewhere?

Comment: I appreciate your thanks, but it's getting a bit much now. You don't need to overdo it. I drew the entire image myself using ChemDraw.

Comment: The formatting is indeed beautiful.